# sed command to extract all the lines between 2 tags

Tags: xml, sed

I'm using `sed` on DOS to extract the content of a XML file between 2 tags.

It works great, except for one little thing...
I don't want to display the lines of the tags I'm searching for.

Here is what I do :

```
sed -n "/<ITEMS/,/<\/ITEMS/p" 1.xml
```

My only concern is that it display also the 2 lines containing `<ITEMS>`.

Solution is near, but I need some help, please!

Comment: In the general case, sed is not an appropriate tool for parsing XML.

Answer (score 0):

You are here:

```
echo "<foo>
<bar>
<item>
line 1
line 2
</item>" | sed -n '/<item/,/<\/item/ p'
```

```
<item>
line 1
line 2
</item>
```

What you want is

```
echo "<foo>
<bar>
<item>
line 1
line 2
</item>" | sed -n '/<item/,/<\/item/ {//! p}'
```

```
line 1
line 2
```

The tricky bit here is `{//! p}` -- the empty regex `//` matches the *previous* regular expression. If that previous regex does *not* match, print the line.

---

An example demostrating where parsing XML with regexes doesn't work: nested tags:

```
echo "<foo>
<bar>
<item>
line 1
line 2
</item>
<item>
  line 3
  <item>
    line 4
  </item>
  line 5
</item>
" | sed -n '/<item/,/<\/item/ {//!p}'
```

```
line 1
line 2
  line 3
  <item>
    line 4
```